# 'Get-AzApplicationGatewayAvailableSslOption' is not in the 'az' command group

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am following [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-configure-ssl-policy-powershell) and run `Get-AzApplicationGatewayAvailableSslOption` command but whatever I do I get:

```
az: 'Get-AzApplicationGatewayAvailableSslOption' is not in the 'az' command group. See 'az --help'.
```

This is version of my Azure CLI:

```
PS U:\> az -v
azure-cli                         2.0.74

command-modules-nspkg              2.0.3
core                              2.0.74
nspkg                              3.0.4
telemetry                          1.0.3

Extensions:
webapp                            0.2.24
```

Answer (score 0):

It is `Az` powershell, not azure cli, you need to install the `Az` powershell module.

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Force
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-2.7.0

Then use `Connect-AzAccount` to login and use the [`Get-AzApplicationGatewayAvailableSslOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-azapplicationgatewayavailablessloption?view=azps-2.7.0).

If it is acceptable, you can use the [azure cloud shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview) directly, no need to install module and login, just use the command directly.

Comment: Immediately I get `PackageManagement\Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'Az'. Try Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module repositories.` upon trying to install Az

Comment: @Yoda Try `Register-PSRepository -Name "PSGallery" –SourceLocation "https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/" -InstallationPolicy Trusted` and then run `Install-Module -Name Az -Force`.

Comment: Tried that too `Register-PSRepository : Use 'Register-PSRepository -Default' to register the PSGallery repository.` Of course obbeying MS advice causes: `> Register-PSRepository -Default -SourceLocation "https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/" -InstallationPolicy Trusted
Register-PSRepository : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.`

Comment: @Yoda If you run `Install-Module -Name Az -Force`, how about the result? It is really related to your specific environment and needs to try many ways.

Comment: @Yoda If it is acceptable, you can use the [azure cloud shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview) directly, no need to install module and login, just use the command directly.

Comment: @Yoda Also try `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy AllSigned -Scope CurrentUser` first.

Comment: @Yoda Could it or the cloud shell can solve your issue?

Comment: Privately it would solve, but I'm not allowed to use it, I will post the solution as soon as I find one, I'll get back to this problem. Thank you for the assist.